# Keep two people's music separate under one iTunes (Match) account

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

My wife and I both have large music collections. We share my iTunes Store account, but she has her own iCloud account.

We recently had cause to add her music to iTunes Match. To keep our music separate, I was just going to make a regular playlist with each of our names and add to each the songs we were respectively interested in.

My idea was that for our Smart Playlists (My Top Rated, etc) we could simply add a criterion that the song must appear in our personal playlists. But lo and behold, iTunes told me that

> Smart playlists that reference other playlists are not supported by iCloud, and will not be uploaded.

Well, that's just great.

We could buy a second iTunes Match account for my wife, but then she would have to start using her personal account for all Store purchases, meaning we'd have to buy all her apps, books, and other non-music iTunes things all over again.

So it looks like I'm screwed, and that the only resolution is going to be that we have to start syncing via iTunes again instead of iCloud. But if there's any workaround that lets me listen to my favorite songs without hearing all my wife's favorite songs, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I don't know all the details, so I won't post an answer, but I don't believe it's as bleak as you've described: your wife can download and use apps and media purchased with your iTunes account despite using her own account on her device. And since iTunes Match music isn't bound by DRM, she could always copy the desired tracks from your iTunes library, upload them into *her* iTunes Match account and manage them separately from your copies.

Comment: You're still paying for two iTunes Match accounts, I realize, but you could look at it as a convenience cost... :)

Comment: If you be a little more specific I can probably help you.